# How to print the next few lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I want to make this script look for a word, which you can determine, and its line number. I want it to print out the text in this line and the two following ones. How do I code the last part (print the next three lines)?

```
def search_passwords():
    file = open("D:\\Libaries\\Documents\\resources_py\\pw.txt",  "r")
    print()
    search = input("Enter service: ")
    print()   
    for line in file:
        if search in line:  
           print(the next three lines)
```

Comment: Try using a variable to remember how many lines you should print after/including the current one: when it's zero, you don't print the line; when it's not zero, you print the line and (EXERCISE 1:) do what with the variable? When you find the keyword, you (EXERCISE 2:) do what with the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some corner cases that you did not mention.

- What if multiple lines have the searching word? What is your expected behavior?
- What if the line right after the matching line has the searching word?
- How large is the file and could you load it in memory?

If there's only one matching, or there won't be any matching in the lines you print right after, then you can use a single counter

```
def search_passwords():
    file = open("D:\\Libaries\\Documents\\resources_py\\pw.txt",  "r")
    print()
    search = input("Enter service: ")
    print()   
    counter = 0
    for line in file:
        if counter > 0:
           counter -= 1
           print(line)
        if search in line:  
           counter = 2
           print(line)
```

However, this will double print the lines if the following lines containing the searching word. You can of course make the second `if` `elif`, but then it will just ignore the following matching pattern.

And, if you only need the first or only appearance, you should break out of the loop once you print everything, not read the whole file.

Just like I said, you need to know the expected behavior and the requirement better, to write a solid program.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a better solution but this is a bit more flexible with a nigher amount of following rows.

```py
def search_passwords():
    file = open("D:\\Libaries\\Documents\\resources_py\\pw.txt",  "r")
    print()
    search = input("Enter service: ")
    print()   
    counter = 3
    found = False
    for line in file:
        if search in line:  
           found = True
        if found:
            if counter > 0: 
                counter -= 1
                print(line, counter)
            if counter == 0:
                break
```

Comment: Yes, you are/were right. I did a typo i wrote `counter =-1` instead of `counter -= 1`.
I further improved my code to break after printing.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach with `not found` error handling:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    try:
        i = lines.index(input('Enter service: '))
        for j in range(i, i+3):
            try:
                print(lines[j])
            except IndexError:
                pass
    except ValueError:
        print('Service not found!')
```